# Datepicker (jQuery) en Laravel 5.4 no funciona

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, css3

Estoy intentando utilizar Datepicker de jQuery en mi vista de Laravel para desplegar un calendario de sólo meses y años, no me aparecen errores en la consola del navegador, pero al hacer click en el input no se activa dicho calendario y no hace nada. Dejo el código de mi plantilla (layouts\app.blade.php) y la vista desde la que hago el input del calendario. Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda!

*APP.BLADE.PHP (PLANTILLA)*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'eGame') }}</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><!--Para la valoración con Rating Stars -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.2/css/star-rating.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        CUERPO DEL LAYAOUT...(BARRA DE MENÚ DE LA APLICACIÓN)
        @yield('content')

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script><!-- ripples.min.js es para el efecto de onda al hacer click -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.2/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
          } );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
        $("#input-id").rating();
    </script>

    <script>
        //$.material.init();
    </script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

VISTA:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

No deberías cargar dos veces la librería de Jquery. Además, deberías ejecutar el código cuando Jquery esté cargado.

Cambia esto:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
          } );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
        $("#input-id").rating();
    </script>
```

Por esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     $("#input-id").rating();
    });     
    </script>
```